# Ignore "[Value_if_false]" when value is true

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I am using an IF function and using the OFFSET function to assign a value in the [value_if_true] and using a 0 for the [value_if_false].  The true OFFSET function was occasionally returning #ref! and #value! errors because it was referencing cells off the worksheet, so I re-coded it in a way that the result would be FALSE [value_if_false] if the cell referenced in the [value_if_true] offset function would be off the sheet.

It seems like Excel doesn't just ignore the [value_if_true] offset function if the value is FALSE.  It is still giving me the same errors.

In an IF function, is there a way to make Excel ignore the TRUE value's function and only post the FALSE value? I know my error is coming from the TRUE value's function because when I change only the TRUE value the error goes away.

This is my formula:

```
=IF(($G$4+$D$18)<L54,((OFFSET($B$55,0,(L54-$G$4-$D$18),,))*$F$4*$N$4),"")
```

Comment: My formula didn't past all the way:   =IF(($G$4+$D$18)<L54,((OFFSET($B$55,0,(L54-$G$4-$D$18),,))*$F$4*$N$4),"")

Answer (score 1):

Use the IFERROR function.

```
 =IF(($G$4+$D$18)<L54,IFERROR(((OFFSET($B$55,0,(L54-$G$4-$D$18),,))*$F$4*$N$4),""),"")
```

You may be able to get rid of the first IF statement using this method... I am unsure what you are trying to do.

```
=IFERROR((OFFSET($B$55,0,(L54-$G$4-$D$18),,))*$F$4*$N$4,"")
```

The function will return the result in the formula unless there is an error and then the second statement is evaluated.